# two arrows on top of each other with css

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm creating a system where users can add some products to their cart and I want them to be able to add some items with a up-arrow and a down-arrow. These arrows are to the right of some text. I've prepared a JSFiddle with the current setup:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xTQ6h/)**

the html:

```
<p>1</p>
<div class="addbutton"></div>
<div class="minbutton"></div>
```

and the css:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

.addbutton {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.minbutton {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now I want the arrows to be on top of each other (with a little margin between them) but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Could anyone help me to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` to your `.addbutton` class. This way it stays it's place, but allows the next element to be rendered on the same position. Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTQ6h/10/)

Comment: It works, thanks! But is there any way to change the margin between the two arrows?

Comment: Try setting `margin-top` of the upper and `margin-bottom` of the lower arrow, to get them well aligned in the middle. just like this http://jsfiddle.net/xTQ6h/26/

Answer (score 2):

change you .addbutton class to block instead of inline-block

```
   .addbutton {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  display: block;
   }
```

Comment: Or just remove the `display` declaration entirely... divs are block elements by default.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that but I want the arrows to be to the right of the text and it doesn't when I chanse the display of the addbutton to block :(

Comment: @Devos50 floating the arrows like this is a generally preferred method than using `position:absolute;` without needing to. You just need to wrap both buttons in something then put that next to the text [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTQ6h/29/)